# Initialising an integer variable with a bit pattern

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

im an absolute beginner and have following task that I need to complete but im totally confused and can't find anything online, hope someone can help out.

Task:

> Let the variable “pattern” be declared as an integer with 32 bits and
> initialised with the bit pattern 0011 1101 0101 1110 0101 1111 0001
> 1010 (3D5E 5F1A). Print the variable, set Bit 7 to 1 and print again.

Given:

```
int pattern = ;
boolean ww = false;
int value = 0;  
        
System.out.println("bitpattern = " + pattern + " --> " +Integer.toBinaryString(value));
```

When I understand that right, an integer is by default declared with 32bit so nothing to do for me for this part. But when I try to assign the number 0011 1101 0101 1110 0101 1111 0001 1010 to the "int pattern" I get the error *"integer number too large"*.

where is my misconception ? Does anyone know a tutorial for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  The underscores are not required but make it easier to separate nibbles.  Prefix the string with `0b`.

```
int a = 0b0011_1101_0101_1110_0101_1111_0001_1010;
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(a));
```

prints

```
3d5e5f1a
```

If you have a String of bits you can do

```
String bitStr = "00111101010111100101111100011010";
int v = Integer.parseInt(bitStr, 2);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(v));
```

prints

```
3d5e5f1a
```

For longs you must suffix with an L

```
long longbits = 0b0011110101011110010111110001101000111101010111100101111100011010L;
```

here are other prefixes available

```
int hex = 0x2A;  // prefix with 0x - 42 in decimal
int octal = 023  // prefix with 0 - 19 in decimal
```

Comment: awesome thanks! What does the 0b stand for though? Do you know what to look for to may find a tutorial?

Comment: Just like `0x` if a prefix for hex, `0b` is a prefix for binary.  And a loan `0` is prefix for octal.  Also, I will edit my answer to show how to do longs.

Answer (score -1):

If you had your input in string-form, you could use `Integer.parse(input, 2)` [see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)).

In your case you could so that: `value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pattern), 2)` (enclosed in try catch)